# Clementine : cannot get visualisations to work anymore

Tags: clementine

yesterday i installed clementine and it was working with visualisations. today i installed something ; cli-visualiser and some other programs, to find out clementine only starts minimized and will not change to full window or any window anymore. so i uninstalled clementine and i have tried all packages in the repo of xubuntu, also snap versions and flathub etc. all now have the same problem ; no visualisations anymore. i used to have 100+ orso from milkdrop visuals and those are not there anymore, even not on a new reinstall of clementine. how to get visualisations back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok sorry after some meddling i found what is going on;
it seems i need the version of clementine from the main ubuntu/xubuntu software app, then the config file of clementine

```
/.var/app/org.clementine_player.Clementine/config/Clementine/clementine.conf
```

has some configs which seem not to reset after exiting the program, that means if the main window is minimized it stays in the tray as icon with no way to maximize it. this config persists after removal of clementine.
so i found out that under

```
[main window]
hidden=false
maximized=true
```

this needs to be set as above
then clementine starts as normal with access to the visualisations.
i feel real noob now